# Lightning components: pass an attribute down to other (not nested) components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

How to I pass an attribute (on any variable) down to other components in an application. Here is what I am working with:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" description="gos_teastHarness">
  <div class="body">
    <c:gos_notificationsTest />
    <c:gos_environmentToggle />
    <c:gos_explicitPermissioning />
  </div>
</aura:application>
```

in my `gos_environmentToggle` component I have a checkbox, and depending on it's state, an attribute it assigned a sting value. Now I want to pass that attribute down to `c:gos_explicitPermissioning` component, but not sure how. 
I was playing around with Application type events, but no luck.

Any recommendations? Is there a way to declare a Global attribute of some sort that can be accessed from anywhere? The tricky part is that `c:gos_explicitPermissioning` also has nested components that all need to access that attribute.

Edit >>> more code

```
/// Event code
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="gos_EnvironmentChangeEvt" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="instance" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

```
/// gos_environmentToggle.cmp
<aura:component description="gos_environmentToggle"
                implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="selectedEnvironment" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="getEnvironment" type="c:gos_EnvironmentChangeEvt"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:gos_EnvironmentChangeEvt" action="{!c.handleApplicationEvent}"/>
    <div dir="rtl">
        <div aura:id="envhead" class="slds-form-element envheared">
            <div class="one">Environment </div>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none three">{!v.selectedEnvironment}</span>
            <div class="two"><label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
                <ui:inputCheckbox change="{!c.selectChange}" value="true" aura:id="env"/>
                <span id="toggle-desc" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_on"></span>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_off"></span>
                </span>
            </label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>       


///JS 
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {

        let getState = component.find("env").get("v.value");
        console.log('getState ::: '+getState);
        if(getState){
            component.set("v.selectedEnvironment", "Production");
        }
        else{
            component.set("v.selectedEnvironment", "UAT");
        }
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:gos_EnvironmentChangeEvt");
        let getEnvironment = component.get("v.selectedEnvironment");
        evt.setParams({ "instance": getEnvironment});
        evt.fire();
        console.log('getEnvironment ::: '+getEnvironment);
    },
    selectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        // first get the div element. by using aura:id
        let getEnvironmentBefore = component.get("v.selectedEnvironment");
        console.log('getEnvironment before >>> '+getEnvironmentBefore);
        switch(getEnvironmentBefore){
            case "Production": 
            component.set("v.selectedEnvironment", "UAT");
            break;

            case "UAT": 
            component.set("v.selectedEnvironment", "Production");
            break;
        }
        let getEnvironmentAfter = component.get("v.selectedEnvironment");
        console.log('getEnvironment after >>> '+getEnvironmentAfter);
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:gos_EnvironmentChangeEvt");
        evt.setParams({ "instance": getEnvironmentAfter});
        evt.fire();
        var changeElement = component.find("envhead");
        $A.util.toggleClass(changeElement, "toggle-env");
    },
    handleApplicationEvent : function(cmp, event) {
        var message = event.getParam("instance");
        console.log("init value: " + message);
        // set the handler attributes based on event data
        cmp.set("v.selectedEnvironment", message);
    }    
})
```

Now the next component, is **NOT** nested but rather independent and needs to get that attribute name="instance"

```
/// gos_explicitPermissioning.cmp
<aura:component description="GTR Explicit Permissioning" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="rightPanelCmp" type="Aura.Component"/>
<aura:attribute name="confirmationModalCmp" type="Aura.Component"/>
<aura:attribute name="removePermissionModalCmp" type="Aura.Component"/>
<aura:attribute name="isProduction" type="Boolean"/>
 <aura:handler event="c:gos_EnvironmentChangeEvt" action="{!c.handleEnvChange}"/>
<div>

        <c:gos_viewLeis/>

        {!v.rightPanelCmp}

        {!v.confirmationModalCmp}

        {!v.removePermissionModalCmp}

    </div>
</aura:component>   

//JS
({
handleEnvChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        var message = event.getParam("instance");
        console.log("current value: " + message);
        if (message == "Production"){
            component.set("v.isProduction",true);
        }
        else {
            component.set("v.isProduction",false);
        }
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!! >> instance value: " );
    }
})
```

Comment: You can't have a "global" attribute in that sense. The application event should work, but perhaps you've done something wrong? Maybe you could share more code with us?

Comment: There is a nice blog post for [Lightning Inter-Component Communication Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-inter-component-communication-patterns.html) which would give a good design idea.

Comment: agree with @sfdcfox,  if you post the code what ever you done with events 'll easy to figure out where it is wrong.

Comment: posted more code for review. Please go nuts :)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can use the approach of Ayoola but there is another option. You can use `component.find()` to get component by `aura:id` and directly set the value fo its attribute. For instance:

```
<!--parent.cmp-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="parentAttr" type="String" default="parent attribute"/>

    <c:child aura:id="child" />
</aura:component>

<!--parentController-->
{(
    someFunction: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.find('child').set('v.childAttr', /* set any value you want dinamically */);
    },
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

The application event should be used to pass attribute date between sister components. If you update your question with some code or more context, we can troubleshoot your implementation.

However,

Please see the Salesforce documentation on [data binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm) for passing attributes between parent and child. (Snippet below)
*This is example will update values in real time - (bound expression)*

```
<!--c:parent-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="parentAttr" type="String" default="parent attribute"/>

    <!-- Instantiate the child component -->
    <c:child childAttr="{!v.parentAttr}" />
</aura:component>
```

*This example will instantiate the attribute value and not update automatically - (unbound expression)*

```
<c:child childAttr="{#v.parentAttr}" />
```